# Updating ajax response on child div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am getting the ajax result perfect but I can not show it properly.

I want to show multiple time. So I have this markup

```
<div class="ajax-response-wrap">
<ul>    
    <li><a href="#" id="9,14" class="ajax-post">All</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="ajax-response">Update response here</div>
```

Another markup

```
<div class="ajax-response-wrap">
<ul>    
    <li><a href="#" id="3" class="ajax-post">All</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="ajax-response">Update response here</div>
```

My ajax result is shown in both `<div class="ajax-response"></div>` But I want to only perspective div.

My jquery code

```
success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){
  var $ajax_response = $( data );                   
  $('.ajax-response').html( $ajax_response );                   
},
```

The screenshot
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `But I want to only perspective div.`

Comment: Can you show us the response object? Presumably a JSON string?

Comment: what your response contains?

Comment: Same result on two div. I have attached the screenshot. If I click on Model it should display on first div but it displays on second div also. I want to show only in first div not second div

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

```
success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){                 
  $('.ajax-response').html(data );                   
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not HTML try the following -

```
success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){                  
  $('.ajax-response').text( data );                   
},
```

Comment: This will break if its an html that is getting returned. You have to know the json string and use this accordingly.